# Poors / the poor / poor

Tags: exam-questions

> In Africa there are many poors.

Is the above sentence correct ? Usually we use the article *the* to denote plural e.g. Alms were given to the poor. But using *the poor* after *many* in above given sentence sounds awkward so will we use simply *poor* here or *poors* is all right  ?

Comment: Any reason to down vote the question ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. You must say:

> In Africa, there are many poor people.

As *poor* is an adjective, it cannot have plural endings like a noun.

In English, adjectives are always [indeclinable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indeclinable).

Comment: *Poor* can be either an adjective or a noun. It would be most unusual to use the noun in the plural but it would be possible.in a poetic sense if one was comparing various kinds of poverty or poor people. "The poor people suffer as do the poor animals and the poor crops; in Africa, there are many poors."

Comment: @RonaldSole _Poor_ is only an adjective: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poor

Comment: @RonaldSole I believe that it is a [nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective) (i.e. still an adjective, but used as the head of a noun phrase).

Comment: @User26328 I grant you that most sources back up *poor* as an adjective although its use as a noun is recognised by some - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poor - and it's used as a noun all the time.

Comment: @RonaldSole "The poor", a fused modifier-head noun phrase. "Poor" is *still* an adjective but it functions as a head of the noun phrase.

Comment: @SteveES agreed! It's still an adjective but its modifying function is 'fused' with the head. '

Comment: In Africa, there are many poor people. This is a perfect sentence to me. I am learning English

Comment: To everyone who suggests poor can be a noun without the article **the** this to me is incorrect.  The Cambridge Dictionary link even gives "**the** poor" in the noun section.

Answer (score 1):

*Poor* is an adjective.

However, in English, you can "nounify" many adjectives by using them where nouns are expected.

Doing can indicate you are talking about an entire class of something that has the adjective as an attribute.

*Poor* can and is often used to refer to an economic class.  So it's  frequently used as a noun.  So you can see and use phrases like:

> The poor are frequently at a disadvantage.
>
> There are many poor who cannot partake in much of modern society.
>
> In Africa there are many poor.

However this needs a context where you are talking about economic classes, not individuals.

Comment: Informally, we do use adjectives countably in some cases: *When he eats M&Ms, he always picks out the reds. We have two smalls and one medium left in stock. It's mostly left turns, except on Second Street it's a right.* It's a little undignified to speak of people in this way, however. *There are a lot of poor there* can be legitimate; *There are a lot of poors there* is demeaning, the kind of thing a rich movie villain would say.

Comment: True, because by saying *poors* you're assuming people are in that class.